# pushgateway - ValueError: Incorrect label count

Tags: python, python-3.x, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

This is my below code

```py
def pushgateway(ip_addr, hostname, env_name, services, type):
"""Notify prometheus alerts via pushgateway"""
registry = CollectorRegistry()
label_keys=['ip','hostname','env_name']
label_values=[ip_addr, hostname, env_name]
for key, value in services.items():
   label_keys.append(key)
   label_values.append(value)
assert len(label_keys) == len(label_values).  # this is through
g = Gauge(type[0], f'process status for {type[0]}', label_keys)
g.labels(label_values).set(int(type[1]))
push_to_gateway('localhost:9091',job=f"{service}_{env_name}",registry=registry)
```

While executing I get this error, What am I doing wrong?

```
File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/prometheus_client/metrics.py", line 164, in labels
    raise ValueError('Incorrect label count') ValueError: Incorrect label count
```

Printing the values from metrics.py - I get the below:

`print(f"{labelvalues}  -  {self._labelnames}")` --> (('a', 'b', 'c'),)  -  ('a','b','c')

`len(labelvalues)` is 1 and `labelvalues[1]` is 3 and
`len(self._labelnames)` is 3.

and assert fails:

```
if len(labelvalues) != len(self._labelnames):
   raise ValueError('Incorrect label count')
```

How to fix this ? should i pass it in a different format ?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to unwrap the array of `label_values`. Add `*` before `label_values` in this line:

```py
g.labels(*label_values).set(int(type[1]))
```

Also note that the `Gauge` you create will not appear in the registry that you send to `pushgateway`. You need to pass `registry` to your `Gauge` class instantiation:

```py
g = Gauge(type[0], f'process status for {type[0]}', label_keys, registry=registry)
```

If you don't do that, the metric goes into the default registry:

```
from prometheus_client import REGISTRY
```

Comment: Yes this indeed works, I figured unwrapping the list later that day. Thanks for pointing out the registry part !!